# Use of -line , -lineanchor and -linestop with regexp command in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I am confused about `-line` , `-lineanchor` and `-linestop` options of `regexp` command in TCL.
I tried many examples but still couldn't understand their use.
Please help me in trying to understanding them (and their use)

Thanks

Comment: [The documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M8) seems straightforward...

Comment: What is your real life problem? What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

These are all settings that are only useful with multi-line text. If your string hasn't got newlines in it, they make no practical difference.

- `-lineanchor` changes how `^` and `$` work in the RE so they also anchor at the start and end of a line. (The internal RE flag sequence `(?w)` is equivalent.)
- `-linestop` changes how `.` and `[^…]` works so they don't include newlines; with this option, you only ever match a newline explicitly. (The internal RE flag sequence `(?p)` is equivalent.)
- `-line` is a shorthand for `-lineanchor` *and* `-linestop`, and the option you probably want if you want to do matching in a multiline text where the newlines matter. (The internal RE flag sequence `(?n)` is equivalent.)

I've *never* wanted to specify either `-lineanchor` or `-linestop` on their own. I'm not even sure under what circumstances you'd want it. However, `-line` (well, equivalent of…) is used by Tk when you're matching the contents of the `text` widget, and it's also great when you've read in a file and want to apply a transformation to the lines (a la `sed`) without first splitting the lines into a list of strings.